# Minecraft mcpi выдаёт ошибку при подключении

Tags: python

Minecraft mcpi выдаёт ошибку при подключении

> > > import mcpi.minecraft as minecraft

> > > import mcpi.block as block

> > > mc = minecraft.Minecraft.createл

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in

AttributeError: type object 'Minecraft' has no attribute 'createk'

> > > mc = minecraft.Minecraft.create()

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming.minecraft\mcpipy-master\mcpi\minecraft.py", line 171, in create

return Minecraft(Connection(address, port))

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming.minecraft\mcpipy-master\mcpi\connection.py", line 17, in **init**

self.socket.connect((address, port))

ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение
Дополнен 8 минут назад

Открыл сервер на локалхост написал mc = minecraft.Minecraft.create(локалхост, 54447)
нечего не написало пишу mc.postToChat("") сообзение консоль начала присылать

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.